# Query working in Resultset but not jasper report

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, jasper-reports, ireport

The following Query works when i directly execute in database and even in java project resultset but does not works in Ireport, i suspect problem is count and sum funtions as when i remove them it works fine ..

```
Select ISBN,BookTitle,Author1,Author2,Author3,Category,Edition,Publisher,PublishingYear,Price,BookSelfName,Volume,Language,Subject, sum(case when status='Available' then 1 else 0 end) as Available, count(*) as Total
from Book
group by ISBN, BookTitle
```

Error is

```
Error:General Problem:null Check username and password;is the DBMS active?!
```

Comment: *Check username and password* - that sounds like it is no issue with your query but instead a connection issue. Wrong credentials?

Comment: if i remove the count n sum part it works all perfect, secondly in sqlite no password can be there

Comment: Did you use the same database you want to execute the query? Also, How you connect database in Ireport?